# Rotate Rectangle 2D For Hit Detection

Tags: java, javafx, game-physics

I was looking to rotate a rectangle by a specific angle, as I have a game using java fx which has comets move at an angle. If the rocket intersects with that comet, the game is over. However, a diagonal comet possesses a rectangle at 0 degrees, which covers unnecessary space. I tried using following code, but the rectangles are still 0 degrees:

```
public void isRocketHit(){
    Rectangle2D rocketrec = new Rectangle2D(rocket.getX(), rocket.getY(), rocket.getImage().getWidth(), rocket.getImage().getHeight());
    for(Streak i : rstreaks){

        double width = i.getImage().getWidth();
        double height = i.getImage().getHeight();
        Rectangle2D cometrec = new Rectangle2D(i.gmarkX(), i.gmarkY(), width, height);
        double rotationCenterX = (i.gmarkX() + width)/2;
        double rotationCenterY = (i.gmarkY() + height)/2;

        gc.save();
        gc.translate(rotationCenterX, rotationCenterY);
        gc.rotate(i.getAngle());
        gc.translate(-rotationCenterX, -rotationCenterY);
        gc.fillRect(i.gmarkX(), i.gmarkY(), width, height);
        gc.setFill(Color.AZURE);

        if(rocketrec.intersects(cometrec)){
            play = false;
            System.out.println("HIT");
        }

        gc.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "However, a diagonal comet possesses a rectangle at 0 degrees..."

Comment: The rectangle around the comet image is not rotated at 0 degrees so it fills excess space. The comet is moving at a rotation of an angle but the rectangle is not; so, there is inaccuracy in hit detection using the 'intersects' method of java.

Comment: What does drawing to a graphics context object have to do with collision detection? Please separate these two independent functions.